# mysql innodb buffer pool size which dependencies

Tags: mysql, size, buffer, innodb, pool

I want to dimension RAM dependent on the innodb_buffer_pool_size. But all what I find is the dependence of the innodb_buffer_pool_size on RAM.

Can you tell me on which parameters on the innodb_buffer_pool_size depends? Number of queries? Number of transactions?

I want to find out the formula which calculates the RAM dependent on innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Can you help me? Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: In dependency on which parameters should I choose the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Answer (score 2):

Sizing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`:

- If all the queries/transactions are touching tiny tables *or* tiny parts or big tables, then a tiny buffer_pool is sufficient.
- If you have UUIDs, you need a big buffer pool -- because you can't touch only 'tiny' parts of the table/index via UUIDs; they are too 'random'.
- Bigger than 70% of RAM is dangerous because it could lead to swapping, which is *terrible* for performance.
- That's 70% of *available* RAM -- need to  leave room for the OS, code, other caches, etc.
- When you change RAM, change the buffer_pool_size.  Or the other way around.
- Bigger is better.
- Much bigger than the total size of all data and indexes is unnecessary (wastes RAM).
- Too small leads to inefficient operation of most operations involving InnoDB.
- the buffer_pool is a *cache*.  Computer Science discusses what that means and what the ramifications are.

So, the simple formula "set it to 70% of *available* RAM".

There are various metrics in `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` that can say whether the buffer_pool is "big enough".  But they are useful only after setting the size, then running for a while.  And they only say "there are lots of reads/writes", they don't say whether or by how much to change the size.

If you would like me to analyze the STATUS (after it has been up at least a day), provide

- How much RAM
- `SHOW VARIABLES;`
- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`

I will check those formulas, plus a couple hundred others.